# How to remove the word chapter from the chapter headings

Tags: r, bookdown

I define a chapter heading of

```
--- 
title: "Example"
author: "me"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
documentclass: book
---

# Introduction
```

Which then renders as:
Chapter 1 Introduction

But I would like it to read:
1 Introduction

How can I remove the word 'Chapter' from the headings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you started with the [bookdown-demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo) repo, the chapter name was defined in [`_bookdown.yml`](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo/blob/5cbac774e8e95cd107c02088d90ad6eaee711100/_bookdown.yml#L4). You can set it to an empty string or remove it. The relevant doc is in the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/internationalization.html).

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: This works when generating HTML output, but doesn't seem to work for PDF.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @ms609 Please see the last link in my answer.

Comment: @YihuiXie, I've set the chapter_name parameter in the ui section of the _bookdown.yml settings, as the Bookdown Book seems to suggest.  This does change the chapter name when I render to HTML, but not to PDF.  If I've understood you rightly, it sounds like it should also affect the PDF?

Comment: No, that is not correct. Please read at least the first two paragraphs following the last link in my answer.

Comment: @YihuiXie, any idea how to add the the word "Chapter" to a book created in html with Quarto?  I can't seem to get this to work and I couldn't find anything in the Quarto documentation on this?

Comment: @StatsStudent Sorry I don't know. You may ask on Quarto's discussion board on Github.